# Zoom in and Zoom out functionality is not working as expected in D3 chart and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

In my D3 chart, Zoom in and Zoom out functionality is not working as expected in D3 chart.

It is zooming the full graph, not just the drawn line and area. Expected behaviour should be only zoomed in and zoomed out graph chart, not the x-axis and y-axis.

When I am Using `d3.zoom()` using below code -

```
.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
   svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
 }));
```

But the above code updates the axis as well. So I tried to add clip-path and tried to use it but it's not working.

```
   // A function that updates the chart when the user zoom and thus new boundaries are available

    const updateChart = () => {
      // recover the new scale
      var newX = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xScale);
      var newY = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(yScale);

      // update axes with these new boundaries
      xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(newX));
      yAxis.call(d3.axisLeft(newY));

      // update circle position
      scatter
        .selectAll("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
          return newX(d.Sepal_Length);
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
          return newY(d.Petal_Length);
        });
    };

    var zoom = d3
      .zoom()
      .scaleExtent([0.5, 20]) // This control how much you can unzoom (x0.5) and zoom (x20)
      .extent([[0, 0], [containerWidth, containerHeight]])
      .on("zoom", updateChart);

    var svg = d3
      .select(this.refs.chart)
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", containerWidth)
      .attr("height", containerHeight)
      .call(zoom);

    // Create the scatter variable: where both the circles and the brush take place
    var scatter = svg.append("g").attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");
```

This scatter should move the circles for zoom in & zoom out. My working code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-bell-qqwwe) -

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to remake this outside the react, you must follow d3 zoom hierarki,

1. Draw the defs,
2. Draw the clip,
3. Draw item you want to move inside the clip,
4. Update element

after you zooming remember the scale is changing please use the new scale to update all of your element if you not do that it will fall to follow the zoom.

```js
var data = [
      {
        startTime: "1567765320049",
        magnitude: 0,
        startupMagnitude: 0,
        startupRunningStatus: "IN_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1567851720049",
        magnitude: 0,
        startupMagnitude: 0,
        startupRunningStatus: "IN_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1568024520049",
        magnitude: 10,
        startupMagnitude: 10,
        startupRunningStatus: "IN_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1568283720049",
        magnitude: 10,
        startupMagnitude: 0,
        startupRunningStatus: "OUT_OF_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1568629320049",
        magnitude: 0,
        startupMagnitude: 10,
        startupRunningStatus: "OUT_OF_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1569061320049",
        magnitude: 0,
        startupMagnitude: 0,
        startupRunningStatus: "IN_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1569579720049",
        magnitude: -20,
        startupMagnitude: 0,
        startupRunningStatus: "OUT_OF_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1570184520049",
        magnitude: -20,
        startupMagnitude: -10,
        startupRunningStatus: "OUT_OF_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1570875720049",
        magnitude: 0,
        startupMagnitude: 0,
        startupRunningStatus: "IN_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1571653320049",
        magnitude: 10,
        startupMagnitude: -0,
        startupRunningStatus: "OUT_OF_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1572517320049",
        magnitude: 0,
        startupMagnitude: -10,
        startupRunningStatus: "OUT_OF_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1573467720049",
        magnitude: 0,
        startupMagnitude: -10,
        startupRunningStatus: "OUT_OF_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1574504520049",
        magnitude: 10,
        startupMagnitude: -10,
        startupRunningStatus: "OUT_OF_SYNC"
      },
      {
        startTime: "1575627720049",
        magnitude: 10,
        startupMagnitude: -10,
        startupRunningStatus: "OUT_OF_SYNC"
      }
    ];
    
      
  var drawLineGraph = function(containerHeight, containerWidth, data, yLabel, warnLine) {
    // A function that updates the chart when the user zoom and thus new boundaries are available
    var newX = '' 
    const updateChart = () => {
      d3.select("#focusCircle").style('display', 'none')
      // recover the new scale
      newX = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xScale);
      var newY = yScale;


      // update axes with these new boundaries
      d3.select("#axisX").call(d3.axisBottom(newX));
      //d3.select('#axisY').call(d3.axisLeft(newY));

      // update circle position
      scatter
        .selectAll("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
          if (d) {
            return newX(d.startTime);
          }
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
          if (d) {
            return newY(d.magnitude);
          }
        });

      var line2 = d3
        .line()
        .x(function(d) {
          return newX(d.startTime);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
          return newY(d.startupMagnitude);
        });

      var area = d3
        .area()
        .x(function(d) {
          return newX(d.startTime);
        })
        .y0(function(d) {
          return yScale(d.startupMagnitude);
        })
        .y1(height);

      var line = d3
        .line()
        .x(function(d) {
          return newX(d.startTime);
        })
        .y(function(d) {
          return newY(d.magnitude);
        });

        svg.on("mousemove", function() {
        d3.select("#focusCircle").style('display', 'block')
          var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
          var mouseDate = newX.invert(mouse[0]);
          var i = bisectDate(data, mouseDate); // returns the index to the current data item
  
          var d0 = data[i - 1];
          var d1 = data[i];
          let d;
          // work out which date value is closest to the mouse
          if (typeof d1 !== "undefined") {
            d = mouseDate - d0.startTime > d1.startTime - mouseDate ? d1 : d0;
          } else {
            d = d0;
          }
  
          div
            .html(
              `<span>${parseDate(d.startTime)}</span>
          <span>Magnitude: ${d.magnitude} </span>`
            )
            .style("left", d3.event.pageX + "px")
            .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 28 + "px");
          var x = newX(d.startTime);
          var y = yScale(d.magnitude);
  
          focus
            .select("#focusCircle")
            .attr("cx", x)
            .attr("cy", y);
          focus
            .select("#focusLineX")
            .attr("x1", x)
            .attr("y1", yScale(yDomain[0]))
            .attr("x2", x)
            .attr("y2", yScale(yDomain[1]));
          focus
            .select("#focusLineY")
            .attr("x1", xScale(xDomain[0]))
            .attr("y1", y)
            .attr("x2", xScale(xDomain[1]))
            .attr("y2", y);
        });

      scatter.select("#line2").attr("d", line2);
      scatter.select(".line").attr("d", line);
      scatter.select("#area").attr("d", area);
    };

    var zoom = d3
      .zoom()
      .scaleExtent([0.5, 20]) // This control how much you can unzoom (x0.5) and zoom (x20)
      .extent([[0, 0], [containerWidth, containerHeight]])
      .on("zoom", updateChart);

    var svg = d3
      .select('#chart')
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", containerWidth)
      .attr("height", containerHeight);

    var clip = svg
      .append("defs")
      .append("SVG:clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("SVG:rect")
      .attr("width", containerWidth)
      .attr("height", containerHeight)
      .attr("x", 50)
      .attr("y", 0);

    // Create the scatter variable: where both the circles and the brush take place
    var scatter = svg.append("g").attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

    var margin = { top: 50, left: 50, right: 50, bottom: 80 };

    var height = containerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var width = containerWidth - margin.left - margin.right;

    var xDomain = d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.startTime;
    });
    var yDomain = d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.magnitude;
    });

    var xScale = d3
      .scaleTime()
      .range([0, width])
      .domain(xDomain);
    var yScale = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .range([height, 0])
      .domain(yDomain);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

    var line = d3
      .line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return xScale(d.startTime);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return yScale(d.magnitude);
      });

    var line2 = d3
      .line()
      .x(function(d) {
        return xScale(d.startTime);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return yScale(d.startupMagnitude);
      });

    var area = d3
      .area()
      .x(function(d) {
        return xScale(d.startTime);
      })
      // .x0(function(d) {
      //   return xScale(d.startTime);
      // })
      // .x1(function(d) {
      //   return xScale(d.magnitude);
      // })
      .y0(function(d) {
        return yScale(d.startupMagnitude);
      })
      .y1(height);
    // .y0(height)
    // .y1(function(d) { return yScale(d.magnitude); });

    // var area = d3
    //   .area()
    //   .x0(function(d) {
    //     return xScale(d.startTime);
    //   })
    //   .x1(function(d) {
    //     return xScale(d.startTime);
    //   })
    //   .y0(function(d) {
    //     return yScale(d.magnitude);
    //   })
    //   .y1(function(d) {
    //     return yScale(0);
    //   });

    // var area = d3
    //   .area()
    //   .x(function(d) {
    //     return xScale(d.startTime);
    //   })
    //   .y0(function(d) {
    //     return yScale(d.magnitude);
    //   })
    //   .y1(yScale(0));

    // Define the div for the tooltip
    var div = d3
      .select("body")
      .append("div")
      .attr("class", "tooltip")
      .style("opacity", 0);

    var g = scatter
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")");
      
    var g2 = svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + margin.top + ")");

    g.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "area")
      .attr("id", "area")
      .attr("d", area);

    g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("id", "axisX")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    g2.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("id", "axisY")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(yLabel);

    g.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")

      .attr("d", line);

    g.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line2")
      .attr("id", "line2")
      .attr("d", line2);

    g.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return xScale(d.startTime);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.magnitude);
      })
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        if (d.startupRunningStatus === "OUT_OF_SYNC") {
          return 5;
        }
      })
      .attr("class", "circle");

    //legend code
    svg
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", 40)
      .attr("cy", 380)
      .attr("r", 6)
      .style("fill", "#1391d8");
    svg
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", 40)
      .attr("cy", 400)
      .attr("r", 6)
      .style("fill", "red");
    svg
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", 60)
      .attr("y", 380)
      .text("Startup Config")
      .style("font-size", "15px")
      .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle");
    svg
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", 60)
      .attr("y", 400)
      .text("Running Config")
      .style("font-size", "15px")
      .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle");

    // focus tracking
    var focus = g.append("g").style("display", "none");

    focus
      .append("line")
      .attr("id", "focusLineX")
      .attr("class", "focusLine");
    focus
      .append("line")
      .attr("id", "focusLineY")
      .attr("class", "focusLine");
    focus
      .append("circle")
      .attr("id", "focusCircle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("class", "circle focusCircle");

    //grid line
    const make_x_axis = () => {
      return d3.axisBottom(xScale);
    };

    scatter
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "grid")
      .attr("transform", "translate(50," + (height + 50) + ")")
      .call(
        make_x_axis()
          .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
          .tickFormat("")
      );

    var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) {
      return d.startTime;
    }).left;
    var parseDate = d3.timeFormat("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
    g.selectAll("dot")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "overlay")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)

      
      svg.on("mouseover", function(d) {
        console.log('ok')
        focus.style("display", null);
        div
          .transition()
          .duration(200)
          .style("opacity", 0.9);
      })
      .on("mouseout", function() {
        focus.style("display", "none");
        div
          .transition()
          .duration(300)
          .style("opacity", 0);
      })

      .on("mousemove", function() {
        var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
        var mouseDate = xScale.invert(mouse[0]);
        var i = bisectDate(data, mouseDate); // returns the index to the current data item

        var d0 = data[i - 1];
        var d1 = data[i];
        let d;
        // work out which date value is closest to the mouse
        if (typeof d1 !== "undefined") {
          d = mouseDate - d0.startTime > d1.startTime - mouseDate ? d1 : d0;
        } else {
          d = d0;
        }

        div
          .html(
            `<span>${parseDate(d.startTime)}</span>
        <span>Magnitude: ${d.magnitude} </span>`
          )
          .style("left", d3.event.pageX + "px")
          .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 28 + "px");
        var x = xScale(d.startTime);
        var y = yScale(d.magnitude);

        focus
          .select("#focusCircle")
          .attr("cx", x)
          .attr("cy", y);
        focus
          .select("#focusLineX")
          .attr("x1", x)
          .attr("y1", yScale(yDomain[0]))
          .attr("x2", x)
          .attr("y2", yScale(yDomain[1]));
        focus
          .select("#focusLineY")
          .attr("x1", xScale(xDomain[0]))
          .attr("y1", y)
          .attr("x2", xScale(xDomain[1]))
          .attr("y2", y);
      });

    svg
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", containerWidth)
      .attr("height", containerHeight)
      .style("fill", "none")

      .style("pointer-events", "all")

      .call(zoom);

    // warn line

    // if (
    //   warnLine &&
    //   yDomain[0] < warnLine.lineValue &&
    //   yDomain[1] > warnLine.lineValue
    // ) {
    //   g.append("line")
    //     .attr("x1", xScale(xDomain[0]))
    //     .attr("y1", yScale(warnLine.lineValue))
    //     .attr("x2", xScale(xDomain[1]))
    //     .attr("y2", yScale(warnLine.lineValue))
    //     .attr("class", "zeroline");
    //   g.append("text")
    //     .attr("x", xScale(xDomain[1]))
    //     .attr("y", yScale(warnLine.lineValue))
    //     .attr("dy", "1em")
    //     .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    //     .text(warnLine.label)
    //     .attr("class", "zerolinetext");
    // }
  }
  
    drawLineGraph(410, 700, data, "Magnitude", {
      lineValue: 0,
      label: "Startup Config!"
    });
```

```css
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #e0e0e0;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}

.line2 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #2e59cf;
  stroke-width: 0.3px;
}

.circle {
  /* fill: white;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2px; */
  fill: steelblue;
  stroke: steelblue;
  /* stroke-width: 2px; */
}

.area {
  fill: #2e59cf;
  stroke: none;
  opacity: 0.1;
}

.zeroline {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #1391d8;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-dasharray: 8 8;
}

.zerolinetext {
  fill: #1391d8;
}

.overlay {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.focusLine {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
}

.focusCircle {
  fill: red;
}

div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 2px;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  background: lightsteelblue;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.grid .tick {
  stroke: lightgrey;
  stroke-width: 0.7px;
  stroke-dasharray: 8 8;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.grid path {
  stroke-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div className="App">
  <h1>Chart</h1>
  </div>
 <div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: I understood the approach, But I can see Y Axis is not showing now.

Comment: The axis Y does not show up cos it drawing inside the clip and the clip begins with x=50 your y-axis will be cropped, look at the code when i draw clip, i just  edit it and make it outside the clip, sorry didn't check that

Comment: What i see you have clip with value but it's not used anywhere ?

Comment: yes, i just named it on the variable, so i can point it to you, not the program, to make you understand, i update the answer still can see Y-axis not showing? - Believe me it hard to explain something to people

Comment: You are correct, https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-leftpad-yhm8h I have added this code in my react app, One issue which is still there is on zoom in and zoom out we are seeing focus circle on the corner if you notice.

Comment: you say "I understood the approach" but you don't, see point 4 on my answer dude you need to update the element every time you zoom it, that include the style on tip function, i update the answer, pleaseunderstand the concept

Comment: Thanks for the help.. Accepted as an answer.

Comment: Kekkutan, 
I just wanted to know, https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-leftpad-yhm8h I am facing some wired issue with mouse over data it is not working as expected,